# Fluent API zero-to-one Relacionamento 0-1 - trazendo resultados de outro relacionamento

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dataannotations, fluent-api

Estou tentando fazer o relacionamento entre meu `Cliente` e o `CieloToken`, tentei com `Fluent API`  e `Data Annotation`, misturei os dois e não funcionou.

Na verdade ele executa, porém mesmo que o `Cliente` não tenha `CieloToken` ele acaba trazendo algum dado mesmo que seja de outro cliente!

**Model:**

```
public class Cliente
{
      [Key]
      [Column("intid")]
      [ForeignKey("ConfigCliente")]
      [Display(Name = "IDC")]
      public int ClienteId { get; set; }

      public virtual ICollection<Boleto> Boletos { get; set; }

      public virtual ConfigCliente ConfigCliente { get; set; }

       public virtual CieloToken CieloToken { get; set; }
}
    //No caso acima quero trazer o CieloToken lembrando que ele não é obrigatório, alguns clientes não tem.

    public class CieloToken
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("int_ID")]
        public int CieloTokenId { get; set; }

        [Column("int_IDC")]
        [Required] //tentativa
        [ForeignKey("Cliente")] //tentativa
        public int ClienteId { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<CieloTransacao> cieloTransacao { get; set; }
        public virtual Cliente Cliente { get; set; }
    }
    //Aqui em CieloToken, caso exista sempre terá um Cliente
```

Quando eu faço

```
var cliente = db.Clientes.Find(3);
```

**Ele retorna um CieloToken, mesmo que esse cliente(3) não tenha!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cliente tem um CieloToken ou CieloToken tem um Cliente?

De acordo com o que você me informou, eu faria a entidade limpa (sem data annotations) e resolveria tudo no Fluent API. O codigo ficaria mais ou menos assim:

**Model Cliente:**

```
public class Cliente
{
    public int ClienteId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Boleto> Boletos { get; set; }
    public virtual ConfigCliente ConfigCliente { get; set; }
    public virtual CieloToken CieloToken { get; set; }
}
```

**Model CieloToken:**

```
public class CieloToken
{
    public int CieloTokenId { get; set; }
    public int ClienteId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CieloTransacao> cieloTransacao { get; set; }
    public virtual Cliente Cliente { get; set; }
}
```

**Classe ClienteConfig (Fluent API):**

```
public class ClienteConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<Cliente>
{
    public ClienteConfig ()
    {
        HasKey(c => c.ClienteId);

        Property(c = c.CieloTokenId)
            .isOptional();

        //Configurar outras Propriedades...
    }
}
```

**Classe CieloTokenConfig (Fluent API):**

```
public class CieloTokenConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<CieloToken>
{
    public CieloTokenConfig()
    {
        Haskey(c => c.CielTokenId);

        //Configurar outras Propriedades...

        HasOptional(c => c.Cliente)
            .WithRequired(cl => cl.CieloToken);
    }
}
```

**Na sua classe de contexto, coloque este método:**

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ClienteConfig());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ClienteTokenConfig());

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Na sua Controller faça o db.Cliente.Find(*int*);

Comment: o CieloToken tem um cliente, nem sempre um Cliente tem um CieloToken.

Comment: Então me parece correto. Você já tentou este código?